# Emulate pastetoggle in neovim

Tags: paste, neovim

The pastetoggle option [has been removed](https://neovim.io/doc/user/news-0.9.html) from neovim and replaced by "Just Paste It(tm)". However, in my setup (ssh + screen) for some reason, the pasting does not work automatically and neovim attempts to autoformat the text I am pasting. Also, sometimes I would like neovim to autoformat the text that I am pasting.

How can I setup a manual switch between autoformatting and no autoformatting? The `paste` and `nopaste` settings still seem to work.